# Add MediaType to existing JsonInputFormatter

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm writing a webhook in asp.net core mvc where the caller posts some json. But the Content-Type is set to `application/vnd.myget.webhooks.v1+json`. I just want to have this content type map to the `JsonInputFormatter`.

I did this, but wondering if there is a better way:

```
services.AddMvc( mvcConfig =>
{
    var formatter = new JsonInputFormatter();
    formatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add( 
         new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.myget.webhooks.v1+json") );
    mvcConfig.InputFormatters.Add( formatter );
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can modify the default `InputFormatter` in `ConfigureServices`

```
services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options => {
    options.InputFormatters.OfType<JsonInputFormatter>().First().SupportedMediaTypes.Add(
        new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.myget.webhooks.v1+json")
    );
});
```

...perhaps a slight improvement